# PySpark : How to convert minutes to hours : minutes?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I will convert col in minutes to hours : minutes

| col(min) |
| --- |
| 685 |

I will obtain

| col(min) | col1(h:min) |
| --- | --- |
| 685 | 11:25 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sql functions `div` and `mod` to get the quotient and remainder respectively, and then concatenate them.

```
df = df.withColumn('col1', F.expr('concat(div(col, 60), ":", mod(col, 60))'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html) to transform data from an RDD into one or more columns.

Python builtin function [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) returns the quotient and remainder of an integer division. `divmod(a, b)` is equivalent to `(a // b, a % b)`.

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    685, 180, 80
])

results = rdd.map(lambda x: divmod(x, 60))

print( results.collect() )
# [(11, 25), (3, 0), (1, 20)]
```

Or if you want the result as strings in format `hh:mm`, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) to format the values to your liking:

```py
results = rdd.map(lambda x: '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(x, 60)))

print( results.collect() )
# ['11:25', '03:00', '01:20']
```

If you want to keep both the number of minutes and the resulting `hh:mm` string:

```py
results = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(x, 60))))

print( results.collect() )
# [(685, '11:25'), (180, '03:00'), (80, '01:20')]
```